# How to get latest timestamp file from FTP using UNIX Script

Tags: unix, ftp, ksh

I am writing a shell script; I want to download latest uploaded file from FTP. I want to get latest file of specific folder. Below is my code for that. But it is not working as expected.

File names are in specific format like

```
.../MONTHLY_FILE/
      ABC_ECI_12082015.ZIP
      ABC_ECI_18092015.ZIP
      ABC_ECI_09102015.ZIP
```

Here my return filename should be `"ABC_ECI_09102015.ZIP"`.
Please help me out in this and let me know what mistake I am making.

```
#!/bin/ksh
. ospenv
#SRC_DIR=/powerm/Myway/SrcFiles
SRC_DIR=$PMRootDir/SrcFiles
cd $SRC_DIR
ftp -n gate.usc.met.com  << FINISH
user ftp_abc.com xyz 
##Here xyz is password
cd /MONTHLY_FILE
#mget ls -t -r | tail -n 1`enter code here`
 get $1
bye
FINISH
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly where exactly you made a mistake, but this should do the trick:

`ls -tr | tail -1`

what's mget? why do you have an "enter code here"? What I wrote above should print out the last file... whether you save that into a variable, insert it directly to another action, it's up to you.